# Pthreads and Semaphores- Multiple Producer/Consumer Using C

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

Producer/Consumer Problem using C

I have created multiple producer and multiple consumer threads, the producer thread will sleep for a random time(less than a given integer) and produce a random number, store it in a buffer array....Similarly the consumer thread will sleep for a random,consume the random number produced by the producer thread...
I have to implement a code such that When the buffer is  empty the consumer thread has to wait and producer thread has to start producing and after producer thread produces...the consumer thread should resume consuming.......Similarly when the buffer is full the producer threads has to wait and consumer threads should consume and after consuming, the producer threads should resume.

I m currently using sched_yield() when buffer is full and  when buffer is empty but its not working and an deadlock is occurring.

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance

Please see my code in this link [link](http://pastebin.com/0A8bkgwD)

Comment: You need to provide your code, and describe what it's doing and where it's going wrong, otherwise we just have to guess what's wrong with it.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Please see my code in this link [link](http://pastebin.com/0A8bkgwD)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a way to create a deadlock with sched_yield. Are you doing something like this?

```
char buffer_is_empty;
while (buffer_is_empty){
    sched_yield();
}
```

This may create an infinite loop because you have a data race on buffer_is_empty. That is UB, but generally compilers generate code that keeps buffer_is_empty in a register so it never notices that the memory has changed. To fix this issue you need to use a mutex when using buffer_is_empty. If I guessed wrong please show some code to describe your problem better.